# Xamarin Binding Java Library Issue

Tags: android, binding, jar, xamarin, inflate

**1、I want binding a java library(https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) to xamarin c# for android(IDE:VS2012\Eclipse)**

**2、Bingding method like this(http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/)**

**3、If i use the java code in C#(.cs),it is normally,**

```
kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView wv = new kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView();
wv.DoSomething();
```

**4、if i use the view in the layout(.axml),it is throw a exception**

```
    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
    android:id="@+id/MyWheel"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


ex
```

{Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/163212a9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:895 
  at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (Int32 layoutResID) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.12-series/163212a9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:4252 
  at App5.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0000a] in c:\Users\zhengys.KGHGROUP\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\App5\App5\MainActivity.cs:23 
  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
    at app5.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at app5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView" on path: /data/app/App5.App5-1.apk
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    ... 22 more
}
    base: {Java.Lang.RuntimeException}

**5、Does anyone know what's going on?Is "kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView" wrong path?What's correct?I need you help!
Thank you !!**

Comment: Is that the entire Exception? If not, could you provide the entire Exception please?

You're getting a InflateException, which occurs when a LayoutInflater can't inflate a piece of XML to View(s) and/or ViewGroups. To be able to answer the 'why' we need more information as the Exception message you provided doesn't contain why, only where.

Comment: thank you for your help!I have put the entire exception in my question.

Comment: If I read this exception correctly:

"android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView at " indicates that it is indeed a problem with inflating the WheelView.

"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView" on path: /data/app/App5.App5-1.apk at " seems to indicate that it couldn't find the class (WheelView) that it want's to inflate.

My 1stt guess would be the WheelView class isn't packaged properly together with the application. You could check that by unzipping the APK and checking.

Comment: hi,Frank ,you could reference 3 and 4 in my question,3 is normal and 4 is throw "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException",I think it is different for prefix("kankan.wheel.widget").by the way ,how i check the APK?

Comment: APK's are just zip-files with some added fluff. You can extract their contents with any decent archiver. Inside you should find, amongst other things, all resources and in this case more importantly, all classes.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Comment: no yet,do you have some good idea

Comment: I've posted some steps which may help find a solution for the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51838073/1525503